# Best way to securely store a password that can be retrieved in a SQL Proc?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security

I need to write a stored procedure in SQL Server, that, as part of its operation, pulls data from another data source using OPENDATASOURCE. (PLEASE DO NOT SUGGEST A LINKED SERVER OBJECT).

What is the best way of storing the credentials for the external data source, and retrieving it for this proc?

Comment: Using environment variables are nice to store credentials

Comment: @Cid could you elaborate please?

Comment: I'm using them to store connection strings. IDK how I could elaborate more

Comment: @Cid but isn't the password store in plain text in the environment variable?